# Wrapping code in a function prevents it from working

Tags: function, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I want to wrap my code in  a function (and then put it in functions.php) so that I can call it elsewhere but my code fails as soon as I wrap it in a function.

I think this may be a scope issue, do I have to pass the the post number somehow to the function? If I get rid of the function that's wrapped around the query, the code works fine.

I'm guessing that the code is irrelevant really (although I may be wrong) - it's more to do with the fact that it's a loop and a function.

```
        <?php function getGallery2() { ?>
            <!-- 1. search for any pages with a custom field of 'test' that have a value of 'yes' -->
            <?php query_posts('meta_key=Gallery - Promotion Gallery Photo Link&post_type=page'); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <!-- 2. echo the test field -->
                <?php $link =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Gallery - Promotion Gallery Photo Link', true); ?>
                <?php $alt =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Gallery - Promotion Gallery Photo Alt text', true); ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $link ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt ?>" />
            <?php endwhile;?>

            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php getGallery2(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$post is not in the functions scope.

You can add `global $post;` to the top of the function or you can include it as a parameter like this:

```
function getGallery2($post){
    // code
}

echo getGallery2($post)
```

Code inside a function can only see variables that were created within the same function or in global scope. Meaning the `$post` object is undefined.

//
On a slightly off topic note, you have lots of HTML comments within PHP. You could easily tidy things p by making it all PHP.

EDIT:

```
function getGallery2(){

    global $post;

    // 1. search for any pages with a custom field of 'test' that have a value of 'yes' -->
    query_posts('meta_key=Gallery - Promotion Gallery Photo Link&post_type=page'); 

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        // 2. echo the test field -->
        $link =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Gallery - Promotion Gallery Photo Link', true); 
        $alt =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Gallery - Promotion Gallery Photo Alt text', true); 
        echo '<img src="'.$link.'" alt="echo $alt " />';
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query(); 

} 

getGallery2();
```

Comment: Hi Jim, still no luck I'm afraid. Any ideas?
`<?php function getGallery3($post){
     query_posts('meta_key=Gallery - Promotion Gallery Photo Link&post_type=page');
               
      while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
         $link =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Gallery - Promotion Gallery Photo Link', true);
         $alt =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Gallery - Promotion Gallery Photo Alt text', true); ?>
         <img src="<?php echo $link ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt ?>" />
     <?php endwhile;
     
     wp_reset_query();
    }
    
    echo getGallery3($post) ?>`

Comment: Also, tried to format the comment nicely (not lazy), but formatting StackOverflow comments is so fiddly / annoying.

Comment: Also, not sure why people are suggesting that putting a loop within a function is incorrect - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/the-loop-inside-a-function-some-thing-works-other-dont - so maybe i should use get_template_part instead? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Comment: Makes no difference to put a function in a loop or a loop in a function.

Answer (score 1):

You would have it something like this I think (not tested):

```
<?php function getGallery2() { ?>
    $global post;       
    $link =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Gallery - Promotion Gallery Photo Link', true); ?>
    $alt =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Gallery - Promotion Gallery Photo Alt text', true); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $link ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Then call the function within any loop on any PHP page. Make sense? i.e. don't loop within the function. I don't understand why you don't just use a php include? i.e.

```
require('get-gallery.php');
```

Hope that helps :D

Comment: Hey Kam, thank for this suggestion. I normally use get_template_part instead http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part (not sure what the exact difference is between that and 'require', pretty sure it does the same thing). I wonder what the adv/disadv is between using that and calling a function. Maybe I'll start a new question to answer that?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/get-template-part-vs-action-hooks-in-themes

Above is a discussion about the pros / cons of get_page_template vs. calling a function. Seems pretty much the same. I personally think I prefer get_page_template over a function, I think it's a clearer break than muddling things in functions.php - but at least I know how to do both now :-D

Comment: Also, for those reading, an advantage of putting it in a function would be that you can pass it variables, like this...http://pastebin.com/vsSWKpnh